# reference front and pop_front

Tags: c++, stl

Is this legal?:

```
Sample& sample = stack.front();
stack.pop_front();
```

My program works. But Sample class have `boost::optional<boost::posix_time::ptime> xxx` member and after `pop_front`, `is_initialized()` returns false;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, this is not legal. You must take a copy of the object, i.e. use

```
Sample sample = stack.front ()
```

If you are using a `std::vector`, the `pop_front` call moves the elements behind to the location and your reference points to a different element (the previously second, now first element.)

Comment: You can't do it easily. With `Sample& sample`, you deliberately asked for a reference, so you got one. If performance is not critical, just use `Sample sample =` or (even easier) `auto sample = ` which will copy-by-value per default. Remember: C++ is an expert language, and it's easy to shoot oneself into the foot if you're not careful.

Comment: In general, adding and removing elements to/from containers invalidates references to items inside the container.  There are exceptions, but any time you see a reference to an element in a container, you need to worry about this.  (Kind of like any time you see a call to `new`, your first question should be, where is the corresponding `delete`?)  With a little experience, it will become a habit.

Comment: @Anteru if copying is expensive, how can we use reference?

Answer (score 1):

If `stack` based on `std::deque`. Exactly the same behaviour for `std::vector` and `std::list`.

From standard:

std::deque::**pop_front**:

> Iterators and **references** to the erased element are invalidated. If the element is the last element in the container, the past-the-end iterator is also invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

No, of course not. Once you remove the object from the collection, there's nothing your reference could refer to.